# what is the correct/prefer way of operating repo/service/controller in spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest

From what I understand, `repository` does crud, `service` does all the business logic, and `controller` receives request. So when a request comes in, the order is usually `controller` -> `service` -> `repository` then pass the data back to client.

The problem I'm facing now is most of my apis would involve in multiple repositories. For example, a request of getting list of email for the user. I would need to decode an encrypted string first (done in `UserService`). If success, use the `id` decrypted from string to search for emails (done in `EmailService`). In this case, the request is first routed to `EmailController` then calls `EmailService`. Should I do all the decryption and call `UserRepository` here in `EmailService` or have `UserService` to handle all that? Also, if I wish to return `ResponseEntity`, should `EmailService` return a list of emails or `ResponseEntity`, or have `EmailController` to construct `ResponseEntity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really distinct approaches but in any case I think that two rules have really to be followed.

**First rule : Consistency in the way of proceeding**.
If you decide one or two ways according to some conditions, the most important thing is applying it consistently for any application use cases.

If you create unwanted variations the code reading and maintainability will become a nightmare.

**Second rule : Make reusable which is designed to be reusable and design a functional design** and not a "donkey" one-to-one layers design for each entity/resource because each kind of entity/resource doesn't live alone.

---

Here you refer to this use case :

> a request of getting list of email for the user

Here is a way to process.
I don't tell that it is "the way". It's just my way.

1) Having a one-to-one mapping between the rest controller and the service layer may simplify really your design :

- `EmailController`-> `EmailService`
- `UserController`-> `UserService`

But note that it has a caveat.
 If you repeat a similar logic in distinct services classes, it will probably mean that a reusable service used by multiple rest controllers should be introduced.
In this case, you could have for the controllers, a one-to-one mapping between the Controller and the Service layer, that is : `EmailController` that communicates with an `EmailService` plus potentially multiple other common services used by `EmailController`.

From your context, here is a concrete example where a common service should be introduced. 
Suppose this task :

> "I would need to decode an encrypted string first"

is performed in multiple use cases processed by different controllers, for example  `EmailController` and `UserController`, it is much better to extract the processing in a dedicated service rather than duplicate it both in `EmailService` and `UserService`.

So  `EmailController` would have these dependencies :

```
- EmailController  -> EmailService
                   -> EncryptingService
```

And the same goes for `UserController` :

```
- UserController   ->  UserService
                   ->  EncryptingService
```

2) Services are not designed to have always a one-to-one mapping with the repository layer.
Repositories are indeed designed to be reusable by any services that need them to accomplish their tasks.
So of course `UserService` is bound to communicate with `UserRepository`.
But if `UserService` also needs to retrieve some email entities that are not directly associated to a `User` entity as an entity relationship, `UserService` has to interact with `EmailRepository` to accomplish this task.

So according to your needs, you could have a one-to-one mapping as dependency in `UserService` :

```
- UserService  ->  UserRepository
```

or more dependencies :

```
- UserService  ->  UserRepository
               ->  EmailRepository
```

3)  About this last question

> Also, if I wish to return ResponseEntity, should EmailService return a
>   list of emails or ResponseEntity, or have EmailController to construct
>   ResponseEntity?

Don't mix responsibilities otherwise layers loose their values.
Services perform/return functional things and have to be designed to work in this way.
The `ResponseEntity` wrapping has to be performed in the layer handling HTTP Response, so in the Rest controllers only.

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated correctly `Services` contain business logic so they shouldn't be concerned about decryption, IMO this should be hidden within the `Repository` implementation that is what's causing your design issues with both business logic being mixed with CRUD logic.

`Repositories` can return paginated results, which is an interface which can be both in the `Service` and `Repository` layer. Then in the `Controller` turn the paginated result into a `ResponseEntity`, for responding to the request. Don't let the `ResponseEntity` venture outside of the `Controller`.